# Transparent Activity in Android

Tags: android, filter, screen, transparent, tint

I would like to make a full screen transparent activity in Android so that it would act as a screen filter. My goal is to tint the activity a color so the whole screen looks tinted. Clicks should still be registered even if the filter is there. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: If by "Clicks should still be registered even if the filter is there", that is not going to be possible. If your activity is in the foreground, it will get the click events. Other people implementing this sort of screen-tinting stuff are probably using a `Service` to put an overlay `View` on the screen that implements the tint.

Comment: @CommonsWare How does an app like this do it? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haxor&hl=en

Comment: As I wrote in my previous comment, other people implementing this sort of screen-tinting stuff are probably using a `Service` to put an overlay `View` on the screen that implements the tint.

Comment: Oh, okay thanks. Where do you think I can go to learn about these kinds of things?

Comment: Well, that's a rather specialized topic. I don't have any resources that I can recommend at the moment -- sorry!

Comment: @throwaway123 You want it to be displayed on top of everything that can be displayed on the device (e.g. third-party apps, system apps), or just on top of one of your other `activities`?

Comment: @blipinsk On top of everything that can be displayed on the device